# A firewall is blocking incoming connections.

Tags: iis, vpn, firewall

To begin with, I am using clients (console applications) on remote computers that send me some data to my IIS server. The server is a regular computer running windows 7 with the default firewall (control panel->System and security->Windows firewall) turned off. Although there doesn't seem to be anything that could possibly be blocking my connections there is something. Until recently mcafee was self-installed (came with the computer when it was bought) and was blocking the connections until I uninstalled it. Everything was fine until today where my rooter rebooted and blocked me again. I have to mention that there are clients running through VPN connections that are not affected and still working.

Comment: `The server is a regular computer running windows 7` - Yeah... this... not so much. I would suggest taking a look at the port forwarding, NAT and firewall rules/ACL's on the router.

Comment: Ok it was port forwading causing the trouble. As soon as I added http to the computer's IP connections started reaching me.